# Sort a occurrence matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to sort a co-occurrence matrix.
I have a sparse matrix like this:

```
[0 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
```

There's a way in Python to sort rows and columns in order to get a matrix with blocks containing the ones?
I would apply a process like shown in occurrence matrix here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are looking for.
Do you wish to obtain at the end :

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Best Regards
Mathieu

Comment: Yes! It could be something like this. In general I'm trying to get a representation (ordering) of rows and columns to make all ones be grouped, like in a cluster.

Comment: I've found sklearn.cluster.CoClustering, that makes something like that.

Comment: Hello @VinB. Instead of sorting you could count the number of 1 and then fill a matrix with the ones and the rest by 0.